# How to use JNI without having to add jvm.dll location into Environment Variables Path

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface

One way to make JNI work is to go into `Environment Variables` and add into `User` or `System` `Path` the folder where `jvm.dll` is located (`.../bin/server`). But this means that on a client machine, when your app is launched, you need to check if the path is added, and if it isn't, to add it.

But instead of doing this, can you give the location to `JavaVMOption`, or using another way, but inside the code and not having to add that location to `Environment Variables`?

I'm using `Eclipse Adoptium` which will be added with the app files with a license agreement, so the location will be dependent to where the app is placed/installed, making the option with `Environment Variables` a bit annoying as the location could change, so you need to remove the old one and add the new one each time in this situation.

This is what I use to create the `JVM`, where `javaLocation` is `std::string`, and it is given as a parameter for the function which contains the location of the app folder:

```
    javaLocation.insert(0, "-Djava.class.path=");
    javaLocation.append("Data\\Java");
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = &javaLocation[0];
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
    JNIEnv* env = nullptr;
    jint rc = JNI_OK;
    if (jvm == nullptr) {
        rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    }
    else {
        rc = jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);
    }
    delete[] options;
    if (rc != JNI_OK) {
        if (rc == JNI_EVERSION)
            return "JNI_EVERSION";
        else if (rc == JNI_ENOMEM)
            return "JNI_ENOMEM";
        else if (rc == JNI_EINVAL)
            return "JNI_EINVAL";
        else if (rc == JNI_EEXIST)
            return "JNI_EEXIST";
        else
            return "JNI_FATALERROR";
    }
    return "JNI_CREATED";
```

This question was asked before in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75243074/using-jni-without-having-to-add-jvm-dll-path-inside-environment-variables-user) thread and was marked as "**This question already has answers here**", but unfortunately the answer given there doesn't apply to JNI, and it is a general solution for **DLL** files.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the linked answer does not apply or how you could not get it to work? The JVM is, after all, just another DLL to be loaded... Alternatively, have you considered the generic LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress route? You only need `JNI_CreateJavaVM`, after all...

Comment: It doesn't apply because you can't just simply copy `jvm.dll` and paste it in the same location with .exe file. It doesn't work like that. And if this doesn't work, then it will look into Windows, and of course it is not there, which it means it will then will look into PATH, and this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you read the second and third answers in that thread? There are other options than bundling jvm.dll with your exe or searching PATH, namely SetDllDirectory and LoadLibrary(Ex) as I hinted at in my first comment.

Comment: See [this question](/questions/28778933/deploying-jre-via-jni-jvm-dll-not-designed-to-run-on-windows-or) for a snippet you can steal: it loads the jvm.dll by absolute pathname, which you can get from querying %JAVA_HOME%, the registry, specific configuration somewhere, or just searching the filesystem.

Comment: Yes, it did work with LoadLibrary. I had some problems before, but now I managed to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: Suggest you write a self-answer for other people to find, then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestion @Botje gave (thank you!), I tried yet again using `LoadLibraryA`, and this time I managed to make it work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <jni.h>
#include <Windows.h>

JavaVM* jvm = nullptr;

std::string createVM(std::string location) {
    std::string jvmLocation = location;
    jvmLocation.append("ThirdParty\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jre-17.0.7.7-hotspot\\bin\\servers\\jvm.dll");
    HMODULE hJVMDLL = LoadLibraryA(jvmLocation.c_str());
    typedef jint(JNICALL* fpCJV)(JavaVM**, void**, void*);
    if (hJVMDLL != NULL) {
        fpCJV JNI_CreateJavaVM = (fpCJV)::GetProcAddress(hJVMDLL, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
        location.insert(0, "-Djava.class.path=");
        location.append("Data\\Java");
        JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
        JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
        options[0].optionString = &location[0];
        vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
        vm_args.nOptions = 1;
        vm_args.options = options;
        vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
        JNIEnv* env = nullptr;
        jint rc = JNI_OK;
        if (jvm == nullptr) {
            rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
        }
        else {
            rc = jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);
        }
        delete[] options;
        if (rc != JNI_OK) {
            if (rc == JNI_EVERSION)
                return "JNI_EVERSION";
            else if (rc == JNI_ENOMEM)
                return "JNI_ENOMEM";
            else if (rc == JNI_EINVAL)
                return "JNI_EINVAL";
            else if (rc == JNI_EEXIST)
                return "JNI_EEXIST";
            else
                return "JNI_FATALERROR";
        }
        return "JNI_CREATED";
    }
    else {
        return "ERROR_LOADING_DLL";
    }
}

//This is just a test for a function I have written in Java, which doesn't take any parameters, and returns a String
std::string createIdentification() {
    JNIEnv* env;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);
    jclass jClass = env->FindClass("JavaMethods");

    if (jClass == nullptr) {
        return "ClassNotFound cI";
    }
    else {
        jmethodID methodID = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass, "createIdentification", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
        if (methodID == nullptr) {
            return "MethodNotFound cI";
        }
        else {
            jboolean isCopy;
            jstring jResult = (jstring)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jClass, methodID);
            const char* string = env->GetStringUTFChars(jResult, &isCopy);
            std::string result = string;
            env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jResult, string);

            return result;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << createVM("D:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\").c_str() << std::endl;
    if (jvm != NULL) {
        std::cout << createIdentification().c_str();
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    return 0;
}
```